# как построить многоугольник по заданным координатам?

Tags: c#

Практикуюсь в c#. Как можно построить многоугольник(произвольный) по координатам и вывести его в bitmap, например.

Comment: [это?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd0c4s09(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: WPF? WinForms? Консольное приложение?

Comment: @VladD мне кажется для `Bitmap` не имеет значения, все равно нужно подключать `System.Drawing`, а это GDI+. Или я не прав?

Comment: @rdorn: У WPF есть свой https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используй [`Graphics.DrawPolygon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd0c4s09(v=vs.110).aspx).

**Рисуем многоугольник:**

```
public void DrawPolygonPoint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

    Point point1 = new Point(50, 50);
    Point point2 = new Point(100, 25);
    Point point3 = new Point(200, 5);
    Point point4 = new Point(250, 50);
    Point point5 = new Point(300, 100);
    Point point6 = new Point(350, 200);
    Point point7 = new Point(250, 250);
    Point[] curvePoints = {
        point1,
        point2,
        point3,
        point4,
        point5,
        point6,
        point7
    };
    e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(blackPen, curvePoints);
}
```

**Рисуем многоугольник в Bitmap:**

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width, pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height);

using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
// Рисуем так-же, как в примере выше
}
// Выводим в pictureBox:
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
// Сохраняем:
bmp.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Png);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics;
Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0), 5);
g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 10, 10, 100, 50);
```

Comment: ```многоугольник(произвольный)```

Comment: Я сишарпа не знаю, но что-то мне подсказывает, что rectangle это не очень произвольный многоугольник